# Create user without UserManager in Asp.Net Core Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-3

On an ASP.NET Core 1.1 application with ASP.NET Identity I created a user:

```
PasswordHasher<User> hasher = new PasswordHasher<User>();

User user = new User {
  Email = "john@company.com",
  Username = "john@company.com
};

user.PasswordHash = hasher.HashPassword(user, "johnpass");

context.Users.Add(user);
context.SaveChanges();
```

The user is created but when I try to sign using the following it fails:

```
SignInResult result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync("john@company.com", "johnpass", false, true);
```

I then tried to create the user using the UserManager:

```
PasswordHasher<User> hasher = new PasswordHasher<User>();

User user = new User {
  Email = "john@company.com",
  Username = "john@company.com
};

await userManager.CreateAsync(user, "johnpass");
```

Now I am able to sign in. It seems the problem is with HashPassword method.

Does anyone knows how to create the user without UserManager?

**UPDATE**
I tried to create a UserManager without reeling on Injection because I am creating my test data on a Console Application and not on the Web Application:

```
var userStore = new UserStore(Context);

var userManager = new UserManager<User>(userStore, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
```

The user is created but I am still not able to sign in.

Comment: It's not just the password hash, but also the security stamp.

Comment: The security stamp? Can you give me an example how to solve it?

Comment: Well you've already got the answer: use the `UserManager`

Comment: That is the point ... I am trying not to use it since I am injecting test data using a Console application so outside of the web application context. And it seems UserManager expects a bunch of classes to be injected in it and on my Console Application I don't have that.

Comment: The user manager class doesn't really need that much injecting. It takes a `UserStore` which in itself takes a `DbContext`. Shouldn't be that hard to figure out.

Comment: I tried to create a UserManager instance on the console application and not in the web application and I was able to create a user but still not able to sign in ... I added an update. Any idea what am I missing?

Comment: Miguel, check this out - works like a charm. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42447607/2708357

Answer (score 3):

you have to do the following things:

```
userManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(domainUser);
        domainUser.NormalizedUserName = domainUser.NormalizedEmail = domainUser.UserName = domainUser.Email;
        await userManager.UpdateNormalizedUserNameAsync(domainUser);
        await userManager.UpdateNormalizedEmailAsync(domainUser);
        await userManager.UpdateAsync(domainUser);
```

and if you set up in your config email confirmation

```
var token = await userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(domainUser);
await userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(domainUser, token);
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the following scenario in login.

> 1. get the user using userName or Email.
>      `user = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(usr => usr.UserName == userName);`
> 2. Check if this user has this password or not using:
>      `userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, password);`

where userManager is an object from `UserManager<User>`